# how to do expert animated swiping layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I dont know what is this called , but i want to make my layout work like this, i got a linear layout inside a layout like this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                .....

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

and below of this i got recycler view which height size is not more than the layout

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/form_dosen_list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"

                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mhs3_TV1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

                    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"

                    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".9"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"

                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray"
                    />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and i want to make this linear layout gone ( animated went to above and gone) by swipe up
and then focusing this recycler and make this recycler view height become match with layout
i know i can jst simply use simple scrollview but its not like what i wanted

Comment: I think CoordinatorLayout is what you're looking for

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen ok ill that check out,  edit: yap seem that what i am looking for